# delete parent entity triggers no validation

Tags: javascript, breeze

i'm using breeze 1.4.8.

let's say i have an order with related customers (the real model differs from that, just for simplification)
in my case the relationship is defined as 1 to many and the FK is not nullable.

Situation:
i have some orders and all the customers in cache locally.

now if i delete  a customer which is already used in one or more orders (also locally) i don't get any feedback from breeze. after setting customers:

```
entity.entityAspect.setDeleted();
```

i would expect validation errors popping up, first of all already on the client. 
but this is not the case so i was hoping for my safe harbour (the database model) to throw some exceptions...but nope

currently it goes through the `saveChanges()` method and it hits the server side where all related orders are hit in the  `BeforeSaveEntity()` - Method which feels unnecessary to me.

In the end nothing gets changed (besides the deleted state locally) but at least i would like to have some feedback from either breeze on the client or the serverside (server breeze)

maybe there went something wrong with my database model. i've recreated the relationship, updated my model multiple times but without success.

metadata: http://pastebin.com/BjwLgULc

model order (transactions):  http://pastebin.com/PSGsZGxR

model customer (vehiclemodel): http://pastebin.com/SW9Wj4ze

part of beforesave entity code which gets hit unecessarly: http://pastebin.com/N99ucY6P

not sure what i'm missing, any enlightment would be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you get as a response from server when save fails?

Comment: i see the POST from my saveChanges() and the Status stays on (pending)

Comment: so no there is no response

Comment: additional note: when i check the orders changed after deleting the customer i get a huge list. so breeze just modifies all the related orders on clientside. in my opinion this is already wrong and validation should have kicked in before...

Comment: on server side i'm using ef5 and BreezeWebApi, BreezeWebApiEF

Comment: You should get some error message like "foreign key is not nullable" or something like that. Try to add breakpoints and see what is really going on. If status says Pending, that means server is stuck on something and requires your attention to fix the bug, catch exception or something similar. If you use VisualStudio and your project is running, execution will stop and it should point out an exception in VS.

Comment: thanks, i've published the project and in the "real" environment i get the messages back. then i was trying to debug the serverside code just to recognise that it suddenly worked... so i have no idea why it was not working before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm checking the count of related transactions now on the serverside before issuing a delete:

```
// used for now for checking if a parent key related to transactions can be deleted (masterdata.js)
function checkTransactions(foreignKey,id) {
    var query = EntityQuery.from("AllTransactions").where(foreignKey, '==', id).take(0).inlineCount();
    return query.using(manager).execute().then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);
    function querySucceeded(data) {
        return data.inlineCount;
    }
}
```

another strategy would be to use an Deleted property on the model. but then additional logic in the dropdown lists would be needed...

concerning the entities which shouldn't get modified in cache i've created an uservoice: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5363277-don-t-change-related-entities-in-cache-if-the-fk-r